# Crawler symfony2 filter show node list empty

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, goutte

Im scraping a web using Goutte/Symfony2 and i have a problem with a filter,

i have in $msg the crawler (part of the web), if i print the html i can see inside of $msg a div with class .mola, why if i filter $msg to get the text from .mola i get `The current node list is empty` ?

```
$msg = '<div class="mola_wrap"> 
            <span class="mola" title="titleinside">109</span>'; // in $msg are more code

$msg->filter('.mola')->text();
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $msg is a Crawler object which contains this html

```
<div class="mola_wrap"> 
    <span class="mola" title="titleinside">109</span>
</div>
```

your code is just fine, maybe the website you are crawling does not have .mola class in some pages

Comment: `$posts[$i]['likes'] = trim($msg->filter('.mola')->first()->text());` get the same, node is empty

Comment: could you please post some more html code so i can see the problem because the code above works

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kaseOga/92d68e7f3216a2f50e32 here is all the html (i get these doing an echo $msg->html();)

Comment: can you try doing $mola = new Crawler($msg->html()); and then call $mola->filter('.mola')->text();

Comment: don't forget to add use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler; at the top

Comment: I'm VERY retard cause i had the same problem with other filter before this with same $msg and the problem is $msg is a Crawler of a bucle, some post can have span.mola and other post can't have... the solution is simple adding a if counting if exist o no :P sorry and thanks!!